# Creating new variable based on conditions of different columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-conditions, recode

can someone please help me with creating a new variable in R? I need to tell R something like this:

```r
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(c = if_else(x == y, x, ifelse(x != y, y, ifelse(is.na(x), y, ifelse(is.na(y), x, NA))))
```

of course, in this form, it doesn't work.
If a value in the first column is equal to a value from the second column - use the value from the first column,
if they are not equal - then use the value from the second column,
if there is NA in the first column, but there is some value in the second column, then use the value from the second column.
if there is NA in the second column, but there is some value in the first column, then use the value from the first column.
(+ the values in x and y are characters)

this is the outcome in the new variable "c" I wish for:

| x | y | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| NA | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | NA | 6 |
| NA | NA | NA |

Comment: When you have several nested `ifelse` functions, a good practice simplifying lecture is to use `case_when` function from `dplyr` package

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually simplify this to just one `if_else()`:

```
library(dplyr) 

data <- data %>%
  mutate(c = if_else(is.na(y), x, y))
```

Result:

```
   x  y  c
1  1  1  1
2  1  3  3
3 NA  5  5
4  6 NA  6
5 NA NA NA
```

Or for the same result, use `dplyr::coalesce()`:

```
data <- data >%
  mutate(c = coalesce(y, x))
```

**Why this works**

For your first condition, `if_else(x == y, x, …)` — if `x == y`, it doesn’t matter if you take `x` or `y` because they are by definition the same. So you could instead write this as `if_else(x == y, y, …)` and get the same result. For your last condition, `ifelse(is.na(y), x, NA)` — that final `NA` will only be reached if `x == y` and `x != y` and `is.na(x)` and `is.na(y)` are all `FALSE`, which is impossible. So you don’t need it. At this point, all of your remaining conditions yield `y` except for one — when `y` is `NA`. So we can write as a single `if_else()` to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,NA,6,NA),
                 y=c(1,3,5,NA,NA))

df <- df %>% 
        mutate(c=case_when(is.na(x) & !is.na(y) ~ y,
                           !is.na(x) & is.na(y) ~ x,
                           x==y ~ x,
                           x!=y ~ y))
```

Output:

```
> df
   x  y  c
1  1  1  1
2  1  3  3
3 NA  5  5
4  6 NA  6
5 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
We could use twice `ifelse` and with `coalesce`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(c = ifelse(x==y, x, y),
         c = ifelse(is.na(x) | is.na(y), coalesce(x,y), c))

   x  y  c
1  1  1  1
2  1  3  1
3 NA  5  5
4  6 NA  6
5 NA NA NA
```